# In CakePHP, What does ComponentRegistry do?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I created a component and when I saw the Test code for the component, the skeleton code created:

```
public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $registry = new ComponentRegistry();
        $this->Precio = new PrecioComponent($registry);
    }
```

¿What is the ComponentRegistry object (`$registry`) for?

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, it's an object where components are registered, ie a collection of component instances. In your application it's the controller that holds [a component registry instance](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_components), it uses the registry to [load and instantiate components](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_loadComponent), and that's where the component receives a reference to the registry via its constructor.

Components are using the registry to get access to the controller that they are attached to, and to load components themselves, it's a required dependency.

So the generated test is the bare minimum required for testing components, in case needed you can for example pass a controller instance to the component registry via its constructor, so that possible usages of `$this->_registry->getController()` in your component do return a controller:

```
$controller = new \Cake\Controller\Controller();
$registry = new ComponentRegistry($controller);
$this->Precio = new PrecioComponent($registry);
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Controller\Controller::components()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_components)**
- **[API > \Cake\Controller\Controller::loadComponent()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_loadComponent)**
- **[Cookbook > Conntrollers > Components > Accessing a Component’s Controller](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#accessing-a-component-s-controller)**
- **[Cookbook > Conntrollers > Components > Using Other Components in your Component](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#using-other-components-in-your-component)**
- **[Cookbook > Registry Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/registry-objects.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Testing > Testing Components](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-components)**